# Syncing two cells in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to sync two cells on google sheets? So if I have a formula for import data function from another sheet in a column, then I add notes about it in the second column, I would like the second column to auto erase if what is in column 1 changes.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour)  Sheets functions can control what is *displayed*, in a cell but cannot *delete* cell contents.  Consider [editing your question](/posts/175125/edit) to include more details about what you are trying to do and why (see [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)) and also search this site for other similar questions that may provide the answer you need. **Example search: ["\[google-sheets\] clear"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+clear "webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=&q=[google-sheets]+clear")**

Comment: Agree that it seems like a XY problem. There maybe better alternatives here.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/overview); more specifically, you might create an ***installable trigger***. There are other options like using low-code, no-code services like IFTTT, Zapier among many more.

To create a **Google Apps Script** project bound to your spreadsheet. Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. From this, you will learn that you might do the following:

1. On your spreadsheet, click the menu **Extensions** > **Apps Script**.
   A new project will be shown if there is still a need for a bounded Google Apps Script project.
   Tip: Set a project title to prevent having https://script.google.com full of projects named "Untitled project".
2. Write a JavaScript function using Class SpreadsheetApp.
3. Create an installable trigger.
   See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Ideally, you should start by writing the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Algorithm)—the instructions the Google Apps Script engine should follow to execute the changes you want to be made automatically.

It would help if you decided how the JavaScript function will be run during the algorithm creation. One option is to use an on-change trigger or a time-driven trigger.

Note: Using an AI like ChatGPT might only be effective if you are familiar with Google Sheets, Google Apps Script and JavaScript. It might be possible to use ChatGPT to start from zero, but you should be aware that this might be time-consuming, especially for those who aren't familiar with prompt engineering.